# Is it normal my wired internet connection is capped?

Tags: pi-4, ethernet, connection, internet, ethernet-port

I'm experimenting quite a surprising slow internet connection on the Pi. I scrolled a lot through the web and I'm unable to figure out whether it's supposed to be that way or not: some people seem to get real GB Ethernet on their Pis while other don't (I read it can be due to the way stuff are soldered on some revs/versions of the board) and I still don't get why the difference, so I hopped someone would know the answer here so I can better understand and revise, if needed, my projects :-)

I already asked on Reddit but couldn't get a clear answer: some discarded the question, arguig that people keep complaining about the Pi's internet speed, while others just said I didn't need that much for my use-case (turning it into a multimedia platforme for Netflix, Youtube, RetroPi and RPG battlemaps), but those answers didn't gave and explanation so I'm still in search for that.

**Informations:**

- I've got a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.4, and RJ45 cat 5e, 6, 7 and 8 to test with (none of them worked for GB ethernet on the Pi so it's not about the cable).
- I've got optical fiber connection at 1Gbps on my PC (avergage 950 DL / 380 UL) so it's not about my provider.
- No VPN are active (or anything else than normal connection).
- My Pi, on the same conditions as my desktop PC, gets ~100 Mbps DL / 140 Mbps UL, so I guess there is something happening on the board but I read on several blog post that the soldering issues they had with the RPi3 (which capped ethernet connection due to USB wiring) were supposed to be solved on the RPi4.
- I've got two RPi4 B: one is 4Gb ram and the other is 8Gb ram -- both have those limitations.

In the end, I'm trying to figure out if I was just out of luck and got 2 functionnal boards on which the Ethernet connection has issues despite being Pi4, or if there is just some config file I need to correct (Jeff Geerling seems to get a lot out of his RPi4!) or if I just should go for another sbc like Odorid N+ in order to get what I want from them.

Comment: It depends **heavily** on how you are running your test; e.g. are your measurements taken on the amount of data written to the SD card? If so, you're **not** measuring Ethernet speed. Suggest you [read some of these](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=raspberry+pi+4+ethernet+speed+ltests&t=ffab&atb=v278-1&ia=web) to understand how the testing is done.

Comment: @Seamus I was just using https://www.speedtest.net/ but I'll look more closely to your link, thanks. I just tried speedtest-cli and interstingly enough it states a 600 Mbps connection while their website says it's still at 80 Mbps… go figure ^^